# Prototype / Scriptaculous intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, prototypejs, scriptaculous, javascript-intellisense

How do I get intellisense for Prototype / Scriptaculous like we get for jQuery in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but I really doubt there is any for now.

For now, either you write your own and share with the world or wait for someone to create them.

PS: jQuery intellisense support was released as a hotfix for VS.NET. It makes sense as jQuery is sort of '[endorsed](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/07/setting-up-visual-studio-intellisense-for-jquery)' by the MS guys. Chances for them to release similar support for other JS framework is unlikely I'll say.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly not perfect, but you can get a little bit by adding

```
/// <reference path="path/to/prototype.js" />
```

to the top of your JavaScript files. Actually, if you have a JS file open in Visual Studio and you drag the prototype.js file into your open file, it will automatically add that reference for you.

This will give you **very** poor IntelliSense support, but perhaps it is better than nothing.